# how to ensure multiple systems generate the next unique value in a single sequence when all systmes run in paralell

Tags: python, validation

I'm a novice / amateur so please forgive the lack of technical language. I have a scenario where I have multiple devices running simultaneously, each need to generate the next available unique ID sequentially in a shared sequence and validate that the values being set is unique in the shared database. The data base will be cloud based and transactions could be sent directly to it over wifi / 4g but latency could/will prevent the individual devices from Being able to validate uniqueness and return the next sequence without getting mixed up. My current proposed solution is to have an on premise server where the devices will send the data for validation and then this server will send the data to the cloud DB but part of the idea is that the devices should be able to easily move locations. Does anyone have any advice on how I could handle these simultaneous validations?

Comment: You would have a backend server running somewhere which will have access to the database. Database management systems support auto incrementation on an id field, and you can generate unique ids in your backend or set up a trigger to do that through dbms when a record is added. Essentially your database would be the one ensuring uniqueness

Comment: thanks @Jeremy for the response, i think i may not have given a great explanation. imagine i have 2 devices, both of which will print a unique serial barcode from a predetemrined range.

Comment: both devices will run in paralell the trigger on each device cannot be predetermined and the rate of the trigger is driven by mechanical process. so device one could be triggering every 10secs and device 2 could be trigering eveyr 15 secs for example. when the process is triggered on each device it will need to check the next available sequence number then print it then it will be scanned and submitted to the database with some quality data.

Comment: this will liekly scale up frequently to have 10 or more devices all running using the same range. i did think about reseving a portion of the sequnce for each device before each process is started but one of the requirments is that the barcodes should be serilised in the same sequence they were printed accross all the devices. at the moment the best option i think of is to have a local server with a wired connection to all sevres. but id liek to find a way to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I think Jeremy is still right. If you need the sequence you can add a timestamp, which is still more accurate than validation time. You could also generate one unique value per device per time step using a pre defined order within one time step.